# System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException клиент не может обработать ответ от сервера

Tags: c#, winforms, asp.net, com, веб-служба

Вкратце: Есть веб сервис(ASP.NET, .NET-3.5) и есть клиент(WinForms, .NET-4.5). У сервиса есть dll-ка для общения с 1С-кой через COM-соединение. Пока не публикую сервис, клиент с сервисом "общаются" нормально(даже в Release). Но после публикации сервиса на IIS сервере, клиент не может обработать ответ от сервиса.

Выкидывает вот-такое исключение: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException

Дополнительные сведения: Тип содержимого text/html; charset=utf-8 ответного сообщения не соответствует типу содержимого привязки (text/xml; charset=utf-8). При использовании особого кодировщика необходимо правильно реализовать метод IsContentTypeSupported.

Невозможно загрузить файл или сборку "Interop.V83" или один из зависимых от них компонентов. Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат.

На обоих проектах стоит конечная платформа х86. "Понизить" фреймворк на клиенте - нельзя."Повысить" на сервисе - нельзя. Добавление этой-же либы к клиенту - не помогло!

Как быть?

Comment: библиотека на 4.5 - работает нормально.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если сервер возвращает `text/html; charset=utf-8` - значит, там что-то сломалось. Причем настолько сильно, что сервис даже не попытался подняться.

Откройте URL сервиса в браузере и посмотрите в чем заключается ошибка.

---

Ошибка *"Была сделана попытка загрузить программу, имеющую неверный формат."* означает несовпадение разрядности.

Настройте версию используемого пула приложений так, чтобы она соответствовала версии библиотеки. Это делается в настройках IIS, подробности по ссылке:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16232432/4340086

Comment: Я разрешил 32-х приложения в пуле! Теперь вылезло вот такое исключение: System.ServiceModel.FaultException

Comment: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Серверу не удалось обработать запрос. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Сбой при получении производства объектов класса COM для компонента с CLSID {181E893D-73A4-4722-B61D-D604B3D67D47} в результате следующей ошибки: 80070005.

Comment: в WebService1.V82Connector.V82Connector.Connect1C()

   в WebService1.Service1..ctor()

Comment: @ВасилийХмеленко Fault - это уже прикладная ошибка.

Comment: @ВасилийХмеленко во-первых, это уже совсем другая проблема - а во-вторых, где-то ее уже тут решали. Ищите.